# PHP: strange behavior with traits

Tags: php, traits

The following code output 1, but why? The property is private and child class shouldn't have an access to it.

```
<?php
trait PropertiesTrait {
    private  $same = true;
}

class PropertiesExample {
    use PropertiesTrait;
    public function foo(){
        echo $this->same;
    }
}
(new PropertiesExample())->foo();
?>
```

Comment: A trait is not a child class. So it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't have child classes. You only have `PropertiesExample`.
2. You are not accessing the property from outside. You have a getter method.

Comment: `echo (new PropertiesExample())->same;` will throw an error, as expected